# Why doesn't button-lock-mode work with python-mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, python-mode

I'd like to have clickable links to JIRA tickets in my Python code from within Emacs.

For example, I use doxygen docstrings in my integration test code, which links a ticket number:

```
def test_user_type_isolation(self):
    """
    Ensure UDT cannot be used from another keyspace
    @jira_ticket CASSANDRA-9409
    @since 2.2
    """
    ....
```

I'd like to be able to click the CASSANDRA-9409 and have it go directly to the [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9409) it's referencing. I found [button-lock-mode](https://github.com/rolandwalker/button-lock) and it works great! However, this elisp works in every mode *except* for python-mode:

```
(require 'button-lock)
(global-button-lock-mode 1)

(setq cassandra-jira-button
      (button-lock-set-button "CASSANDRA-[0-9]+"
        #'(lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (browse-url (concat "https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/"
                         (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
        )
    :face 'link :face-policy 'prepend))
```

It's not just my code though, none of the examples included in button-lock.el work in python-mode either. So, does anyone know what might be causing the conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `button-lock-mode`, but Emacs comes with `bug-reference-mode`, and the very useful sub-mode `bug-reference-prog-mode`.  I would suggest using those instead.  For your use you would want to configure this via `bug-reference-bug-regexp` and `bug-reference-url-format`.

`bug-reference-prog-mode` is handy because it limits its buttonizing behavior to comments and strings -- perfect for programming modes.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank-you! I'll probably use that, but I'll leave this question open in case I can figure out the button-lock-mode because I can envision a few other uses for it still.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to achieve multiple bug tracker hyperlinks using this:  https://gist.github.com/EnigmaCurry/487e2ec34258c68dd48a